# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `defaultValue` of type `string` supplied to `AutoCompleteSearch`, expected `function`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I dont know why, why I am having this kind of error **MUI: A component is changing the default value state of an uncontrolled Autocomplete after being initialized. To suppress this warning opt to use a controlled Autocomplete.** is there anything wrong with my code? please help thanks

**LocationSearch.js**

```
const propTypes = {
    defaultValue: PropTypes.String,
    getOptionLabel: PropTypes.func,
    value: '',
}
const defaultProps = {
    defaultValue: '',
    getOptionLabel: () => {},
}

const AutoCompleteSearch = ({
    defaultValue,
    getOptionLabel,
})
....

return(
   <Autocomplete
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
   />
)
```

//parent

**AddUser.js**

```
 import {LocationSearch} from '../../component/LocationSearch.js'

      <LocationSearch
        freeSolo
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option} // the value of option is the name of the company
        defaultValue={threatLocation.title} //same goes with the defaultValue
        value={suggestedLocations.title}

      />
```

Comment: The `defaultValue: PropTypes.func` need to change to `defaultValue: PropTypes.string` the other error is I dont know

Comment: `defaultValue: () => {}` and `defaultValue: ''`

Comment: thank you about this it solve the 1 problem let me update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### About Prop types:

Given the `LocationSearch` signature provided in `AddUser`, you need to change both:

- `defaultValue` to be a string
  Per the mui Autocomplete API, it is of type any. Since you seem to infer it to be a string, you should probably change its type in the prop types.
- `getOptionLabel` to add input parameter and return value.  Its signature is defined in [mui Autocomplete API](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/) like so

> Signature:
> function(option: T) => string

The overall changes look like this:

```js
const propTypes = {
    defaultValue: PropTypes.string,
    getOptionLabel: PropTypes.func,
}

// default string values are up to you
const defaultProps = {
    defaultValue: "",
    getOptionLabel: (option : string) => "",
}
```

### About the uncontrolled state

It's because you're using `defaultValue`.

In a controlled component, data is handled by the Autocomplete component via callbacks. The alternative is uncontrolled components, where data is handled by the DOM itself. [Controlled vs uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#:%7E:text=In%20a%20controlled%20component%2C%20form,form%20values%20from%20the%20DOM.) is discussed in React documentation.

As of your code, [MUI Autocomplete Doc](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/) says:

> The default value. Use when the component is not controlled.

To have controlled Autocomplete component, you should use `onOpen`, `onChange` callbacks and remove `defultValue`.  An example can be found in [MUI Autocomplete demo](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#controlled-states):

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

const options = ['Option 1', 'Option 2'];

export default function ControllableStates() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(options[0]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{`value: ${value !== null ? `'${value}'` : 'null'}`}</div>
      <div>{`inputValue: '${inputValue}'`}</div>
      <br />
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
          setInputValue(newInputValue);
        }}
        id="controllable-states-demo"
        options={options}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note: you should not remove your questions once they are answered. Even if you have many of them in your post. It confuses future readers.